# Create private Cocoapods Repository from existing repository

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I need to create my own private pods repository of an existing pod (Geofire) which also utilises Firebase.

Can anyone please explain to me how to proceed with the Xcode Project to basically import both libs Geofire & Firebase and create a pod with them or maybe just modify the geofire one to be able to put it on my own cocoapods repo?

Geofire iOS pods:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/GeoFire
https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Github does not let you create private forks of the public repository, you can follow the below steps to create your own separate repo.

- Download the latest version of Geofire project
- Create a private repo in Github and push the code to that
- Follow this [Cocoapods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) to create your Private Pod